# Adding "value" to div

Tags: javascript, variables

My problem is about DIV attributes in JavaScript.
DIV cannot have `value` attribute, but I need to make it have some *"value"* to hold the `i` variable.
Here's an example of what I have:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= endDate; i++) {
  if (i === today.getDate() && dt.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && dt.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear()) {
    cells += "<div class='today'>" + i + "</div>";
  } else {
    cells += "<div onclick='dayChanger()' value='i'> " + i + "</div>";
  }
}

function dayChanger(obj) {
  dt.setDate(obj.value);
}
```

Comment: Use a data attribute instead

Comment: It shouldn't be a value attribute in div. I would use input or another attribute like data-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a div *can* have a value attribute, but it is less common. You should just use data-* attributes.

For example: `<div ... data-value='i'>`.

Then in your handler, you can access it like to:

```
obj.getAttribute("data-value")

// or, if you are not targeting dinosaur browsers:

obj.dataset.value
```

Also, you might consider building the div as an element instead of interpolating, but that is just personal taste. For this small example, it is fine.

Comment: It's not *less common*. `value` is simply **not** a valid [`HTMLDivElement` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem, because I want to get the i "value" but I am getting only the letter "i" from it.

Comment: @David the above is just an example, you probably know how to concatenate a variable with string. If you don't here's a "hint" `\`<div onclick='dayChanger()' value='${i}'>${i}</div>\``